# outlook with windows service

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-services

I created a windows service in order to acces the outlook calender.

```
public SOutlook()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MyLogSrc"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyLogSrc", "MyLog");
        }

        //set our event log to system created log
        myEventLog.Source = "MyLogSrc";
        myEventLog.Log = "MyLog";

        tmrDelay = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        tmrDelay.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tmrDelay_Elapsed);
    }

 void tmrDelay_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        GetAllCalendarItems();
    }
```

the GatAllCalenderItems() is a fct that acces the outlook calender, get the informations needed and then save all in a data base. I've already tested it and it works fine (the timer also works). For some reason this fonction doesn't work in the windows service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        myEventLog.WriteEntry("MyService started");
        tmrDelay.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Can anyone help me please

Comment: One problem may be the account your service runs under. You should also include the code in `GetAllCalendarItems`. When you say "it doesn't work" does it throw an exception, or it just doesn't save anything to your database.

Comment: in the GetAllCalendarItems(), it only gets to the part 
var oCalenderFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
                var outlookCalendarItems = oCalenderFolder.Items;

Comment: yes it doesn't save anything in the database.. even thow it works fine in a windows form

Comment: Under what account is the service running?

Comment: you mean the user? my user is an admin if that's what you mean

Comment: Are you running both the service and your standalone app under the same account? This could well be failing because your service runs under account "A", but when you test as a standalone exe you run it as yourself.

Comment: Yes it's the same account..

Comment: @DanielKelley I tried this in tmrDelay_Elapsed():
string str = "Timer tick " + count;
myEventLog.WriteEntry(str);
count++;             and the service works, it does what it's expected to do. the only problem is when calling GetAllCalendarItems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly does not work? Outlook (or any other Office app) cannot be used in a service.

Comment: there is no way to make the Outlook work in a service?

Comment: No. CDO 1.21 (no longer supported or installed by Outlook, Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) or Redemption (any language) can be used in a service. Outlook Object Model cannot.

Comment: Ok thx, I have no idea what Redemption is but I will look into it

Comment: Can you tell me please how to use the Redemption to acces Outlook Calender?

Comment: Use the RDO family of objects (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm). RDOSession object roughly corresponds to the Namespace object in the Outlook Object Model To get the calendar folder, call RDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).